# Need help creating C++ member functions to represent task with RTOS microcos III

Tags: c++, embedded

The following code is an example of how task are created with micro cos III in c. I am trying to figure how to create similliar code in C++. My problem is how do I instantiate objects and how to use member functions to represent task. Within the create task routine the address of function is passed as argument. How do I do this in C++? Will I need more than one class? New to embedded C++.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "includes.h"

#include "protectedled.h"
#include "protectedlcd.h"
#include "pushbutton.h"
#include "lcd.h"


// Relative Task Priorities (0 = highest; 15 = idle task)
#define  STARTUP_PRIO           1   // Highest priority, to launch others.
#define  DEBOUNCE_PRIO          7   // Every 50 ms, in a timed loop.
#define  SW1_PRIO               8   // Up to every 50 ms, when held down.
#define  SW2_PRIO              12   // Up to every 150 ms, if retriggered.
#define  LED6_PRIO             13   // Every 167 ms, in a timed loop.
#define  LED5_PRIO             14   // Every 500 ms, in a timed loop.

// Allocate Task Stacks
#define  TASK_STACK_SIZE      128

static CPU_STK  g_startup_stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];
static CPU_STK  g_led5_stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];
static CPU_STK  g_led6_stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];
static CPU_STK  g_debounce_stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];
static CPU_STK  g_sw1_stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];
static CPU_STK  g_sw2_stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];

// Allocate Task Control Blocks
static OS_TCB   g_startup_tcb;
static OS_TCB   g_led5_tcb;
static OS_TCB   g_led6_tcb;
static OS_TCB   g_debounce_tcb;
static OS_TCB   g_sw1_tcb;
static OS_TCB   g_sw2_tcb;

// Allocate Shared OS Objects
OS_SEM      g_sw1_sem;
OS_SEM      g_sw2_sem;


/*!
* @brief LED Flasher Task
*/
void
led5_task (void * p_arg)
{
    OS_ERR  err;


    (void)p_arg;    // NOTE: Silence compiler warning about unused param.

    for (;;)
    {
        // Flash LED at 1 Hz.
        protectedLED_Toggle(5);
        OSTimeDlyHMSM(0, 0, 0, 500, OS_OPT_TIME_HMSM_STRICT, &err);
    }
}

/*!
*
* @brief LED Flasher Task
*
*/
void
led6_task (void * p_arg)
{
    OS_ERR  err;


    (void)p_arg;    // NOTE: Silence compiler warning about unused param.

    for (;;)
    {
        // Flash LED at 3 Hz.
         protectedLED_Toggle(6);
                OSTimeDlyHMSM(0, 0, 0, 167, OS_OPT_TIME_HMSM_STRICT, &err);
      }
}

/*!
* @brief Button SW1 Catcher Task
*/
void
sw1_task (void * p_arg)
{
    uint16_t    sw1_counter = 0;
    char        p_str[LCD_CHARS_PER_LINE+1];
    OS_ERR      err;


    (void)p_arg;    // NOTE: Silence compiler warning about unused param.

    // Draw the initial display.
sprintf(p_str, "SW1: % 4u", sw1_counter);
    protectedDisplayLCD(LCD_LINE1, (uint8_t *) p_str);

    for (;;)
    {
        // Wait for a signal from the button debouncer.
        OSSemPend(&g_sw1_sem, 0, OS_OPT_PEND_BLOCKING, 0, &err);

        // Check for errors.
        assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

        // Increment button press counter.
        sw1_counter++;

        // Format and display current count.
        sprintf(p_str, "SW1: % 4u", sw1_counter);
        protectedDisplayLCD(LCD_LINE1, (uint8_t *) p_str);
    }
}

/*!
* @brief Button SW2 Catcher Task
*/
void
sw2_task (void * p_arg)
{
    uint16_t    sw2_counter = 0;
    char        p_str[LCD_CHARS_PER_LINE+1];
    OS_ERR      err;


    (void)p_arg;    // NOTE: Silence compiler warning about unused param.

    // Draw the initial display.
    sprintf(p_str, "SW2: % 4u", sw2_counter);
    protectedDisplayLCD(LCD_LINE2, (uint8_t *) p_str);

    for (;;)
    {
        // Wait for a signal from the button debouncer.
        OSSemPend(&g_sw2_sem, 0, OS_OPT_PEND_BLOCKING, 0, &err);

        // Check for errors.
        assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

        // Increment button press counter.
        sw2_counter++;

        // Format and display current count.
        sprintf(p_str, "SW2: % 4u", sw2_counter);
        protectedDisplayLCD(LCD_LINE2, (uint8_t *) p_str);
    }
}

/*!
* @brief A task to create all of the other tasks and their shared objects.
*/
void
startup_task (void * p_arg)
{
    OS_ERR   err;


   (void)p_arg;    // NOTE: Silence compiler warning about unused param.

    // Perform hardware initializations that should be after multitasking.
    BSP_Init();
    CPU_Init();
    OS_CPU_TickInit();

    // Initialize the reentrant LED driver.
    protectedLED_Init();

    // Create the LED flasher tasks.
    OSTaskCreate((OS_TCB     *)&g_led5_tcb,
                 (CPU_CHAR   *)"LED5 Flasher",
                 (OS_TASK_PTR ) led5_task,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_PRIO     ) LED5_PRIO,
                 (CPU_STK    *)&g_led5_stack[0],
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE / 10u,
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE,
                 (OS_MSG_QTY  ) 0u,
                 (OS_TICK     ) 0u,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_OPT      ) 0,
                 (OS_ERR     *)&err);
     assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    OSTaskCreate((OS_TCB     *)&g_led6_tcb,
                 (CPU_CHAR   *)"LED6 Flasher",
                 (OS_TASK_PTR ) led6_task,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_PRIO     ) LED6_PRIO,
                 (CPU_STK    *)&g_led6_stack[0],
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE / 10u,
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE,
                 (OS_MSG_QTY  ) 0u,
                 (OS_TICK     ) 0u,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_OPT      ) 0,
                 (OS_ERR     *)&err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    // Create the semaphores signaled by the button debouncer.
    OSSemCreate(&g_sw1_sem, "Switch 1", 0, &err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err); 

    OSSemCreate(&g_sw2_sem, "Switch 2", 0, &err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err); 

    // Create the button debouncer.
    OSTaskCreate((OS_TCB     *)&g_debounce_tcb,
                 (CPU_CHAR   *)"Button Debouncer",
                 (OS_TASK_PTR ) debounce_task,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_PRIO     ) DEBOUNCE_PRIO,
                 (CPU_STK    *)&g_debounce_stack[0],
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE / 10u,
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE,
                 (OS_MSG_QTY  ) 0u,
                 (OS_TICK     ) 0u,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_OPT      ) 0,
                 (OS_ERR     *)&err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    // Initialise the LCD driver.
    protectedInitialiseLCD();

    // Create the tasks to catch the button semaphores.
    OSTaskCreate((OS_TCB     *)&g_sw1_tcb,
                 (CPU_CHAR   *)"Button 1 Catcher",
                 (OS_TASK_PTR ) sw1_task,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_PRIO     ) SW1_PRIO,
                 (CPU_STK    *)&g_sw1_stack[0],
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE / 10u,
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE,
                 (OS_MSG_QTY  ) 0u,
                 (OS_TICK     ) 0u,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_OPT      ) 0,
                 (OS_ERR     *)&err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    OSTaskCreate((OS_TCB     *)&g_sw2_tcb,
                 (CPU_CHAR   *)"Button 2 Catcher",
                 (OS_TASK_PTR ) sw2_task,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_PRIO     ) SW2_PRIO,
                 (CPU_STK    *)&g_sw2_stack[0],
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE / 10u,
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE,
                 (OS_MSG_QTY  ) 0u,
                 (OS_TICK     ) 0u,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_OPT      ) 0,
                 (OS_ERR     *)&err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    // Delete the startup task (or enter an infinite loop like other tasks).
    OSTaskDel(NULL, &err);

    // We should never get here.
    assert(0);
}

/*!
* @brief The starting point for the entire C program.
*/
void
main (void)
{
    OS_ERR  err;


    // Disable all interrupts.
    CPU_IntDis();

    // Initialize the operating system's internal data structures.
    OSInit(&err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    // Install application-specific OS hooks.
    App_OS_SetAllHooks();

    // Create the alarm task.
    OSTaskCreate((OS_TCB     *)&g_startup_tcb,
                 (CPU_CHAR   *)"Startup Task",
                 (OS_TASK_PTR ) startup_task,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_PRIO     ) STARTUP_PRIO,
                 (CPU_STK    *)&g_startup_stack[0],
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE / 10u,
                 (CPU_STK_SIZE) TASK_STACK_SIZE ,
                 (OS_MSG_QTY  ) 0u,
                 (OS_TICK     ) 0u,
                 (void       *) 0,
                 (OS_OPT      ) 0,
                 (OS_ERR     *)&err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err);

    // Start multitasking.
    OSStart(&err);

    // We should never get here.
    assert(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im learning c++ I dont understand the entry point member function taskroot explain its purpose? Why are we passing arg to taskroot? and casting it to type cTask? what type of call takes place for task entry point? Everything else make sense to me. Would I need and abstract class for every class or use one abstract class to derive all task objects? Try explaining logic dont give me code I would like to learn how to write code on my own. FYI keep in mind that I would like to create objects that I could pattern after when developing in corporate.

Answer (score 3):

You can if you wanted essentially compile your C code as C++ with very few changes.  If it compiles as C++ it is C++.  That said that is not to benefit from OOP.  In an OO sense, a task might be considered an object, so you would have an abstract task class from which tasks can created.

I have in the past created an entire class library to abstract RTOS primitives (task, semaphore, mutex, timer etc.), and ported it to a number of RTOS - not uC/OS-III, but enough to be confident of its portability to almost any RTOS.  The thing about the task entry point us that it must be a either a regular function or a static member function - the solution is to have a static member function that is the entry point for all tasks but which takes a pointer to the task object, and calls its entry point which is a virtual member.

In my case the static entry point is defined thus (very cut down - just the fundamentals):

```
void cTask::taskRoot( void* arg )
{
    cTask* instance = reinterpret_cast<cTask*>(arg) ;

    // Call task entry point
    instance->threadMain() ;
}
```

Where `cTask::threadMain()` is a pure virtual function.  A concrete task class must inherit `cTask` and implement `threadMain()`.

To start the task there is a member function defined thus, again drastically cut down to just the fundamentals, and I have omitted the actual task creation because my code is not uC/OS-III specific).

```
bool cTask::spawn( int taskpriority, int stack_size, void* stack_ptr )
{
    bool spawned = false ;

    if( !task_spawned )
    {
        if( stack_ptr != 0 )
        {
            // create OS task using native API
            // using  taskRoot() as the entry point and
            // passing the `this` pointer as the user argument
            OSTaskCreate( ... ) ;

            spawned = (OS_ERR_NONE == err) ;
        }
    }

    return spawned  ;
}
```

So using this you might have code that looks like the following:

```
class cMyTask : public cTask
{
    virtual void threadMain()
    {
        // Task loop
        for(;;)
        {
            ... // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
cMyTask mytask ;
static CPU_STK  stack[TASK_STACK_SIZE];

mytask.spawn( MYTASK_PRIORITY, sizeof(stack), stack ) ;
```

There is of course a lot more ot it that that, my `cTask` includes members for delay, schedule locking, passing task events, changing priorities etc.

You'll note that the one user parameter available to the native thread is used to pass the task object instance to `taskRoot()`, so cannot be used by the thread for other purposes.  This is not really a problem in C++ because you can instead pass such data to the sub-class constructor and store it in member data to have it available to `threadMain()`.

Comment: Clifford Thanks for your help. Im learning c++ 1)I dont understand the entry point member function 2)taskroot explain its purpose? 3) Why are we passing arg to taskroot? and casting it to type cTask? 4) what type of call takes place for task entry point? Everything else make sense to me. 5)Would I need and abstract class for every derived class or use one abstract class to derive all task objects? Try explaining logic dont give me code I would like to learn how to write code on my own. FYI keep in mind that I would like to create objects that I could pattern after when developing in corporate.

Comment: 1/2) The underlying operating system requires a pointer to a function - it can only be a regular function or a static member function.  It is used as the OS_TASK_PTR argument to OSTaskCreate.

Comment: 3) So that you can call threadMain() which is not a static member so it can access all object instance member data.

Comment: 4) taskRoot is called by the OS when OSTaskCreate is called via spawn().  In turn taskRoot callse threadMain.

Comment: 5)  You can have multiple instances of a single cTask sub-class, but each task will execute the same thread code.  In your code each task has a different task function, so you would necessarily want to create a different subclass - generally the code you currently have in sw1_task, sw2_task etc. would be in the threadMain of separate cTask subclasses.